# Embedded select referencing its parent's tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay, so this question may seem a little weird, but If someone knows if it's possible it would be a huge help to developing a query that I am writing.

Here's some Pseudo-code of what my current query is doing :

```
SELECT TERMS.Field1
   , TERMS.Field2
   , DISC.Field3
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT Field1
            ,Field2
      FROM
      --various tables
      WHERE
      --various expressions
   ) TERMS,
   (
      SELECT Field3
      FROM 
      --various tables
      WHERE
      --various expressions
   ) DISC
   WHERE
   --various expressions
```

What I want is to be able to add embedded selects into the top-most select statement that is able to refer to what is being returned from TERMS, kind of like this :

```
SELECT TERMS.Field1
   , TERMS.Field2
   , DISC.Field3
   , (
      SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM TERMS
      WHERE
      --various conditions
     )
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT Field1
            ,Field2
      FROM
      --various tables
      WHERE
      --various expressions
   ) TERMS,
   (
      SELECT Field3
      FROM 
      --various tables
      WHERE
      --various expressions
   ) DISC
   WHERE
   --various expressions
```

You may be asking why I don't just put a `count(*)` in TERMS directly, it's because there are a few different conditions that I want to apply to TERMS's output in these selects that I want to be able to count. If there is some way to do this or perhaps suggestions on how to do it in a better way that would be helpful.

Thank you and if this isn't explained clearly please let me know.

Comment: On Oracle 12c you can use `CROSS APPLY` or `LATERAL inline view`, also simple join is sufficient in many cases - but it depends on your query, hard to say looking only on vague pseudo-code.

Comment: Sorry, I would show you the entire code but I'm bound by my companies policies not to. The structure is exactly the same, just with a whole lot of selected fields and expressions in the where clauses. 

part of the reason I don't want to join a TERMS on to my original query in which I count the TERMS is because TERMS is a frequently updated and rather large block of code. maintenance could become very difficult if there were two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that [WITH Clause : Subquery Factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) clause can help in your case:

```
WITH TERMS AS (
      SELECT Field1
            ,Field2
      FROM
      --various tables
      WHERE
      --various expressions
)

SELECT TERMS.Field1
   , TERMS.Field2
   , DISC.Field3
   , (
      SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM TERMS
      WHERE
      --various conditions
      )
FROM TERMS,
(
      SELECT Field3
      FROM 
      --various tables
      WHERE
      --various expressions
 ) DISC
 WHERE
   --various expressions
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are asking - while it may not be the most efficient solution, what you show in pseudo-code should work just fine. Did you try? If you didn't, why don't you try first, and then ask here? If you did try, what happened?

In any case, you can add `COUNT(*)` as an *analytic* function to the inner query. Let `TERMS` be

```
(
  select Field1, Field2,
         Count(*) over () as cnt   --  If you don't need an analytic clause
  from   [various tables]
  ...
) TERMS
```

and then select `cnt` along with the other columns in the outer query.

You may also use `partition by...` and `order by...` and a windowing clause in the analytic `COUNT()` function. Google "Oracle analytic functions" if you are not familiar with them, or post your actual query if you need specific help.

Comment: When using this query the error message I get is "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" pointing to line 6. I'm going to try out analytic functions because that may be exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Marking this as solved, although my original question has not been answered precisely my problem is solved. thanks again!!

Comment: @SidhwenKhorest - of course, you did not provide any actual table names in your original post, so there is no way the solution I provided would work **exactly** as written. You must adapt it to your real-life case.

Comment: I know that I am referring to how I'm still unaware of how to reference a select statement embedded in the FROM clause with a select statement embedded in the SELECT clause. However, like I said, this doesn't matter. My code works now. :)

Comment: @SidhwenKhorest - Ah, I see what you mean. The solution I provided is *instead of* referencing the subquery in `select` like you were trying to do. What you were attempting can be done neatly using the `WITH` clause, as in krokodilko's answer. However, the analytic function way is probably more efficient - you can run the queries both ways and see which is better in your real-life case.

Comment: Yes I am testing out the runtimes now as both seem to be working. Either way I learned something new!